# awk array: print fields after selecting arrays element

Tags: awk

I have used `awk` command to extract maximum value from the dummy file.

```
cat dummy_file

    Cat Felix 3
    Cat Garfield 2
    Cat Tom 1
    Dog Snoopy 5
    Dog Spike 4


awk '{max[$1] =!($1 in max) ? $3 : ($3 > max[$1]) ? $3 : max[$1]} \  
    END {for (i in max) print i,max[i]}' dummy_file

    Cat 3
    Dog 5
```

Additionally to extracted maximum value and arrays element I need corresponding `$2`. For the output like this:

```
    Cat Felix 3
    Dog Snoopy 5
```

My question is - how to print wanted field after selecting arrays element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
{
    if ($1 in max) {
        if ($3> max[$1]) {
            max[$1]=$3
            type[$1]=$2
        }
    } else {
        max[$1] = $3
        type[$1]=$2
    }
}
END {
    for (i in max) print i,type[i],max[i]
}
```